# How to change the percentage width of multiple images based on their order of appearance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Let's say there are three 9* images on the page:

```
<img src="...">
<img src="...">
<img src="...">
<img src="...">
<img src="...">
<img src="...">
<img src="...">
<img src="...">
<img src="...">
```

*Just an example, there won't always be 9 images - could be 5 or 6, etc

How would I make it so that the percentage width of the images correspond to this order:

1st image: width: 100%;

2nd image: width: 70%;

3rd image: width: 30%;

Repeat

Similar to what has been done here:
[image]

Overall, for every image on the page, the width has to be:

100% for the first image,
70% for the second image,
30% for the third image,
Repeat in this order for every other image, e.g:
100% for the fourth image,
70% for the fifth image,
30% for the sixth image,

I believe scripts would need to be used though I am not sure how to do so

Basic Implementation:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    img:nth-of-type(3n+0) { width: 100%; }
    img:nth-of-type(3n+1) { width: 70%; }
    img:nth-of-type(3n+2) { width: 30%; }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

<div class="page">

    <div class="i">
    <img src="http://e794d552b4c822b8205c-27b9cc3fb8731a4a7598943b8a8a6a91.r73.cf1.rackcdn.com/1/1/large.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="i">
    <img src="http://e794d552b4c822b8205c-27b9cc3fb8731a4a7598943b8a8a6a91.r73.cf1.rackcdn.com/1/1/large.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="i">
    <img src="http://e794d552b4c822b8205c-27b9cc3fb8731a4a7598943b8a8a6a91.r73.cf1.rackcdn.com/1/1/large.jpg">
    </div>

</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you display the attempts of doing this yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few fancy CSS3 selectors should do the trick:

```
img:nth-of-type(3n+0) { width: 100%; }
img:nth-of-type(3n+1) { width: 70%; }
img:nth-of-type(3n+2) { width: 30%; }
```

See [the documentation for `nth-of-type` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type).

Note that this will not work in IE8 or earlier, for which you may need to use a JavaScript solution.

Comment: Thanks but this seems to be making every image have a width of 70%

Comment: @Osman How are you using this? Are you placing it inside a `<style>` element or a CSS file that's `<link>`ed from your `<head>`? Could you provide a minimal working example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I have edited the description for this question, I've found out that this only works when all the images are placed inside the same div (so the code in the description won't work)

Comment: @Osman Try something like `div.i:nth-of-type(...) img` for the selector instead. (sorry for the late reply; I'm a bit busy and on mobile right now)

Comment: `.post:nth-of-type(3n+0) img { width: 30%; }`  - Works perfectly! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will set the width accordingly to all images in the page, so adjust the query in `$("img")` to match only the desired images.

```
var sizes = ["100%", "70%", "30%"];
$("img").each(function (idx, elem) {
  elem.width = sizes[idx % sizes.length];
});
```

Comment: Doorknob's approach is preferable though

Answer (score 0):

This would work in IE8, though is less maintainable and not very sexy.  This assumes that your images are the only items inside of an element (eg. a DIV):

```
img:first-child { width: 100%; }
img:first-child + img { width: 70%; }
img:first-child + img + img { width: 30%; }
img:first-child + img + img + img { width: 100%; }
img:first-child + img + img + img + img { width: 70%; }
img:first-child + img + img + img + img + img { width: 30%; }
img:first-child + img + img + img + img + img + img { width: 100%; }
img:first-child + img + img + img + img + img + img + img { width: 70%; }
img:first-child + img + img + img + img + img + img + img + img { width: 30%; }
```